# Why does .NET application fail with error message, "This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running."

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

My .NET Core 3.1 application is working fine for a few hundred users. One user is having trouble. He is running 32-bit Windows 10 on a 64-bit CPU. I am guessing that might be significant because most users are running 64-bit Windows. I have confirmed via a screenshot that he really is using 32-bit Windows with a 64-bit CPU.

To use .NET Core 3.1 desktop apps, users must install the appropriate .NET Core runtime files. I send users to the following page:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/current/runtime

... and tell them to select either 32-bit or 64-bit under the "Run desktop apps" heading. The user has done that, and he downloaded "windowsdesktop-runtime-3.1.5-win-x86.exe" and ran it to install .NET Core 3.1. Unfortunately, he gets an error message when he tries to run the app, "This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you are running."

It's evidently a bug that the message includes "%1". I assume that is an overlooked substitution placeholder.

I believe I am creating the app correctly. Here are the settings from the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.2.2.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.2.2.0</FileVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My platform target is "Any CPU", Prefer 32-bit is unchecked.

So, my question is, why is the user getting the error when he tries to run the app? Is there some .NET install dance he or I needs to do that for some reason is different from other users?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd part library?

Comment: @Magnetron No, I am not using any 3rd-party libraries. The app is very simple. The error occurs before my code gets control.

Comment: Have you tried run your app publishing it as self-contained?

Comment: @Gabriel Hemming No, I use Inno Setup to make a signed installer. It works for all users except the one described in the question. A self-contained exe would be about 35 times bigger and so I chose to have users install the .NET Core runtime as described above. There are frequent updates, and this method avoids frequent large downloads because the runtime is only delivered once, if it isn’t already installed for something else.

Comment: @JohnnyCee you should try to run without Inno Setup, and if that still doesn't work, to publish a self contained. I'm not saying to use in production this way, it's just to narrow the problem down, because maybe it's a Inno Setup issue, maybe it's the installed run-time issue, so just try to do these things to rule them out.

Comment: @Magnetron I think I will create a test project and use VS2019 to make a couple different install packages, i.e., no Inno Setup. I am pretty confident that my Inno Setup install is not the issue, but this will prove it or at least provide some new data and an easier-to-share test case.

Comment: I have forced with the same error - one user is having the same issue: Inno Setup produces this error when running on Windows 7 x64. I can't recreate this error on a fresh installation of Windows 7 (Hyper-V). Furthermore, it looks like the error appears randomly - simply recompiling the installation package solves the issue, so, my conclusion: **it can be fully addressed to InnoSetup**. The bad thing is that I can't predict that the build failed before running the installation on that particular machine.

Comment: @Mar - Those circumstanes don’t match what I see with my application. In my case, the error is not intermittent, it only happens on Win32 running on an 64-bit processor, including both Win7 and Win10, and recompiling the InnoSetup package makes no difference. Also, the error does not occur when InnoSetup is running. It occurs when one the programs installed by InnoSetup is running. It’s not clear from your description if that isnthe same or not.

Comment: @JohnnyCee, sorry I wasn't clear. From your comment, I thought that InnoSetup fails. My issue is the following: 32bit installation package created by InnoSetup fails to start on 64bit Windows 7 with the "not compatible" error message. The error occurs randomly - simple recompiling the installer fixes the issue (sometimes not).